Vite Could not resolve css/js files imported inside external package
I have 2 (private) packages. Package-b exposes react components gets included in the Package-main.
{
  "name": "package-main",
  "dependencies": {
    "package-b": "1.0.0",
  }
}

When starting Package-main (with command "vite") I get following error:
npx vite
yarn run v1.22.22
node_modules/package-b/lib/package-b/src/components/Banner/Banner.js:5:7:
      5 │ import './Banner.scss';

Inside of package-b:
// Banner.js
import './Banner.scss';

.. normal react component ..

This error is thrown foreach file where a scss file is imported. What changes do I need to make in either package-b or package-main to resolve this issue? Ty
(node v18.18.2, tried both vite v5.4.10 and v4.3.9)
